# Writing handlebars in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a small app which is multilingual. The text of the app is coming from the server. The text can be in different language. For now lets stick to Swedish and English. User can switch between languages. What I am trying to do is when the app loads get the text in both languages and store it in models in Ember.

Then I am trying to write a Handlebars helper which will allow me to switch between the languages. For example the data from the server I am getting is in this form.

```
langData: {
 sv_SE: {
  start_page: "..."
 },
 en_US: {
  start_page: "..."
 }
```

My model for this is language.js which is like this

```
App.Language = DS.Model.extend({
    language: DS.attr('string'),
    start_page: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

In my handles bar I am trying to do something like this

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('__', function(key, lang, options) {
   // get the text specified for the language. A function which will check the language model and
   // fetch data for the particular key from it
});
```

I am calling the handles bar like this

```
{{__ start_page en_US}}
```

What I am thinking that, this will return me start page text in English language.

Is this the right way? If not what will be the right way? Also, I will have different text strings which will be used in different hbs files.

Comment: Why not set the language model to the controller? If you switch the language model the template should update automatically.

Comment: yeah but I have different template and every template has different text. So for this way I would have to set different models for every template. I am trying to write a model which would be accessible to every template.

Comment: Will this solve your need? Here I'm extending from the base controller.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xucix/1/edit

Comment: Would that work if I have different templates? Lets say I have another template called foo and in foo I will have want a foo_message which will be in lang array. Would that work? Should I inherit all my controllers from the base controller then?

Comment: It should work as the data is in the controller and all templates have access to the data in the controller. For this to work you should use a common controller(BaseController). You may also be able to separate the language related stuff to a mixin and use that with any controller.

Comment: One more question, the langData array would be filled by data from the server. Once the data is loaded then I want to call this function setupController which is setting up the values. Right now what it does is it shoots before the data is even loaded. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: Im not sure about ur question? Maybe a jsbin will help. FYI promises should be used when you fetch data from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your example code, I am able to do the language switching. I do have one question. Right now I am doing this {{labels.start_page}} in my template file. For example id 'start_page' doesn't exists it will return blank. What if I want to check it somewhere that if that doesn't exists return a string like 'MISSING'. I know I can make an if condition in my template but then I would have to repeat it everywhere. Can I do it in like my basecontroller somewhere?

Comment: I think your above scenario is suitable for a handlebars helper.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Ember-I18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) for a project successfully. It gives you a place to put your translations outside a model. I then load the current language based on a cookie or a setting on the user model. Switching to a different language does require a full-page reload for me, but you might be able to get it to work without that.